# Connect postgreSQL to vapor3

Tags: json, swift, postgresql

I did all the right things for connecting postgreSQLProvider to my project. But after change "provider" from "memory" to "postgresql" in file "fluent" I got the error:

> Configuration error: Key hostname in Config/postgresql.json of type String required.

I must say that I am pretty new for all this stuff. How can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like the `hostname` in your config is probably blank... Trying putting the the host name of your PostgreSQL database there.

Comment: @Nicarus, my host name looking like this:  "host": "127.0.0.1". It's correct, right?

Comment: I don't know where your PostgreSQL database is, but it sounds like it is on the same machine. if so, try "localhost"

Comment: @Nicarus, yes, it's on the same machine. I changed it to "localhost", but i got still the same error((

Comment: Wow, i just change my key "host" to key "hostname", and it's probably work. I'll check it out after a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed in file "postgresql.json" "host" to "hostname".